# Tomcat appends CRLF to the response string

Tags: tomcat, servlets

In my servlet I  send a string to browser as attachment. When I save the attachment to disk and open it, the string was appended with a CRLF (Catrige return, newline). 
Does Tomcat do this or browser do this? How to not have this CRLF appended?

The code:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachemnt; file=.........");  
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
out.println("abcd");
```

There are 3 lines in the saved file from browser: (You can see the CRLF when using notepad++ and turn on "view all charrachters")

1 abcd

2 CRLF

3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRLF seems to be part of the specification for the `println` function of ServletOutputStream, see [Tomcat manual](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream.html).

You could use `out.print` instead of `out.println`.

Answer (score 2):

May be you're missing the UTF-8 encoding.

Try adding:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding( "UTF-8" );
response.setContentType("UTF-8");
```